# Grails - Where to put test files and how to load them

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'd like to ask where is the best place for test files in grails (i.e. data.xml). Is it test/ folder?

How can I load test files in Integration test easily?

Thanks,
Mateo

Answer (score 13):

in test/integration/resources

and then, i.e. if you use spock for testing, you can do something like that:

```
def mediaBundlerService = Mock(MediaBundlerService)
mediaBundlerService.getPath(_) >> [path: new File('test/integration/resources/test-bundle/').absolutePath + "/"]
```