# Where do I put test resources in Grails (2.4)?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'm working on a service class that needs to process some sort of data payload. In my automated tests, I'm adding some mock data to check the behavior of the service for different inputs. I need to extract these mock data to several files so I can reuse them for other tests. Where do I put such file in a Grails (2.4) app? By convention, most Java projects have `src/test/resources` for the purpose, but Grails doesn't seem to consider that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grails - Where to put test files and how to load them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739182/grails-where-to-put-test-files-and-how-to-load-them)

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing unit tests you can put them under test/unit/resources and if you are writing integration tests you put them under test/integration/resources.

Comment: Will Grails recognize `test/unit/resources` are source directory automatically?